# Spring security auth ldap

Tags: java, spring, ldap, protocols

I am using spring-ldap-core (version 2.3.3) and spring-security-ldap (version 5.4.2) plugin in my Sprint boot application.
The application worked ok ... until yesterday.
Yesterday, users receive error

> javax.naming.authenticationexception ldap error code 49 - invalid credentials

After checking other applications written in other languages ​​(php, pascal, C #), I came to the conclusion that the problem may be the LDAP protocol version.

Other applications enforce LDAP version 3.

Can anyone tell me how to enforce this version in spring-security???